# from Jenkins docker push throws "unauthorized: BAD_CREDENTIAL"

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have configured Docker in Jenkins
ref:

https://getintodevops.com/blog/building-your-first-docker-image-with-jenkins-2-guide-for-developers

I am using docker.withRegistry:

```
docker.withRegistry('<private repo>', 'credential_id') {
            app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
            app.push("latest")
        }
```

Build and tagging was successful. But when it is pushing to the repository, I am getting

```
unauthorized: BAD_CREDENTIAL
```

I have configured credentials, still i face this issue. 
Can someone guide me?

Thanks in advance.